# Give notification sound when insert into a database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, notifications

I am using Laravel 5.6 and mysql for my web based application.I have table named notices into my database for inputting notices. When one user will insert a notice into the notices table other users will get a **notification sound.**
How can I do that?

Comment: Try to look into broadcasting: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting

Comment: Take a look at [broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting#introduction).

Comment: where should come from the notification sound?

Comment: @dparoli the web apps will produce a sound to other users.

Comment: if from the browser see the comments above about broadcasting

Comment: As others mentioned you can do this to users currently on your page using broadcasting but if you also want users to receive desktop notifications take a look at the [Notifications API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel's built-in broadcasting system.
Laravel supports Pusher and Redis out of the box with minimal configuration.

Pusher provides a step-by-step guide for setting up web notifications for Laravel: https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-notifications-laravel-pusher-channels.